# Valid /Validated-Difference (XML,DTD)

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

I have a theoretical misunderstanding, maybe caused by the language, hence I apologise in advance for the simpe question. Speaking about XML-documents (-files) and DTD , there are two basic things,the difference of which should be understood: valid and validated.
As explanation for this words stays:

> Valid :  (a)  which is acceptable, because it is true  (b) Which can be
>   used lawfully
>
> Validate :  (a) to check to see if something is correct  (b) to make
>   something valid

Also, one XML-file is valid,when it's written correctly (well-formed) and 
conforms the grammar (DTD) and validate is simply the checking, whether the file is valid,so you (1)validate and then /affter correcting/ (2) the file is valid, that means, that a file can't be valid without to be validated. Is this true,or theoretical it isn't so simple?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is on the mark...

In conventional usage in XML, there is no deep difference between *valid* and *validated*.  Both mean that an XML document adheres to the constraints of an associated schema.

One would usually use ***validated*** in situations where the emphasis is on the act of having run a validating parser successfully on the XML document.

One would usually use ***valid*** in situations where the emphasis is on the state of the file conforming to a schema, regardless of whether this was actually checked by a validating parser or otherwise known to be true.

> Also, one XML-file is valid,when it's written correctly (well-formed)
>   and conforms the grammar (DTD)

That's right...

***Well-formed*** means that a textual object meets the [W3C requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) for [being XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed).

***Valid*** means that well-formed XML meets additional requirements given by a specified schema.

Read more about this distinction here:  [Well-formed vs Valid XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085)